# Userforms to Fill a column

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Edit: Almost solved refer to my most recent comment and the relevant code.

I want a userform to fill in column A of a worksheet based on the selections made on the user form

The user form has 16 check boxes, two list boxes containing the months (jan-dec), and one list box containing years (two digits)

I want the userform to fill in the XX YYY and the ZZ in the string and generate two values for each checkbox selection (one for each month selected) and paste these values one after another in column A

(G:\Reporting\XX_MISSE_YYY20ZZ.xls)

where XX corresponds to the checkbox I select (can be between 1-16 selections in total)
and YYY corresponds to the listbox selection for month (just to reiterate I want there to be two values generated from the two month selections in the list boxes)
and ZZ to correspond to the two digit listbox selection for year

In other words...

What I want the userbox to do is if I select on my user form the check boxes corresponding to AH and AD (for example) and I select mar and Apr for the month listboxes, and 13 for the year listbox my result in column A will be

first value generated would be (G:\Reporting\AH_MISSE_MAR2013.xls) in column A1

second value generated would be (G:\Reporting\AH_MISSE_APR2013.xls) in column A2

third value generated would be (G:\Reporting\AD_MISSE_MAR2013.xls) in column A3

fourth value generated would be (G:\Reporting\AD_MISSE_APR2013.xls) in column A4

Comment: Where aare you storing the "AH","AD", etc. values for each checkbox? (Hint: the Tag property is probably the right answer)

Comment: @Declan_K Haha well perhaps I don't understand userforms too well... I don't have the form in question built I actually asked for assistance on how to build my user form but I'll look into the tag property and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub cbtnSubmit_Click()
Dim sMonth1 As String
Dim sMonth2 As String
Dim sYear As String
Dim cMyControl As Control
Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim iOff As Integer

    sMonth1 = Me.lbMonth1.Value 'get the first month from the listbox
    sMotnth2 = Me.lbMonth2.Value 'get the second month from the listbox
    sYear = Me.lbYear.Value 'get the year

    TargetCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") 'Where we want to start outputing
    iOff = 0 'Start output with no cell offset

    For Each cMyControl In Me.Controls 'Loop through all control on the form
        If TypeName(cMyControl) = "CheckBox" Then 'Finding the Checkboxes
            'then writing the values to the excel sheet
            TargetCell.Offset(iOff, 0).Value = "G:\Reporting\" + cMyControl.Tag + "_MISSE_" + sMonth1 + ".xls"
            TargetCell.Offset(iOff, 1).Value = "G:\Reporting\" + cMyControl.Tag + "_MISSE_" + sMonth2 + ".xls"
            'after I've written two value, "move" down two cells
            iOff = iOff + 2
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The code seems completely right so I don´t understand why it isn´t working... I set the macro to a button on the same userform. The only thing I can think of is that it isn´t referencing my check boxes correctly because I named the list boxes the names in your code but not entirely sure what to do with the check boxes because there are so many.  Should I group them or leave them sepearate? As of right now they are named checkbox 1-16.  Also to give you some background the code runs all the way through with no problems but then the values don´t appear in the target cell. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out, although your code wasn´t exactly perfect I wouldn´t have solved it without you so I will give you the select answer and and up vote thank you so much